# Check if objects in array contain equal properties

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, each with various properties. I want to check if one particular property is equal across all of the objects. e.g.

```js
peopleArr = [
  {
  name: Simon,
  age: 22,
  hair: brown
  },
  {
  name: John,
  age: 22,
  hair: black
  },
  {
  name: James,
  age: 22,
  hair: blond
  }
 ]
```

I need a function that returns true if `age` has the same value across all of the objects in the array, and false if not. I've tried some variations using .every, but can't get it to work with object properties specifically (I'm relatively new). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to include the attempt you mentioned where you tried to use the `every()` method?

Comment: As @esqew, said, please consider the code you tried to resolve this issue.

Comment: What if the property is not defined what should it return?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method and inside the callback check if `age` in all the object is equal to 22. It will return Boolean value and it will return true if all all the object matches the condition

```js
const peopleArr = [{
    name: 'Simon',
    age: 22,
    hair: 'brown'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 22,
    hair: 'black'
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    age: 23,
    hair: 'blond'
  }
]

const res = peopleArr.every(item => item.age === 22);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the .every() method, would be to filter the array and compare the filtered array length to the original array length. Like so

```
const peopleArr = [
    {
        name: "Simon",
        age: 22,
        hair: "brown"
    },
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 22,
        hair: "black"
    },
    {
        name: "James",
        age: 22,
        hair: "blond"
    }
]

const array_val_same = ( arr, val ) => {
    let filtered = arr.filter(el => el.age === val)
    return filtered.length === arr.length ? true : false
}

array_val_same(peopleArr, 22)
```

This is just an alternative, i'd still use .every() though.